# PLSQL: delete patterns in a string

Tags: regex, string, oracle, plsql

I got a dynamic string like this (one of the cases):

```
'DISTINCT type,NULL,DECODE(java_api_name,NULL,initlower(process(object_name)))
,NULL,field_description,NULL,NULL'
```

I want to delete the ",NULL " in the string except  the one inside the DECODE function. Here is the result I want :

```
'DISTINCT type,DECODE(java_api_name,NULL,initlower(process(object_name)))
,field_description'
```

**Update : This is just an example, the rule should be like this : delete NULLs which are not in any braces**

How could I get this? The simpler the better.

Comment: You want to change code in a file or code in a trigger?  What OS are you on?

Comment: @jimmcnamara In a PLSQL procedure. Oralce 10g, I don't think it's relevant to OS. Thanks

Comment: It is if you are running bash scripts to correct a .sql script using sed. You want to change code.  Where is the code now? in a file/program or in the db.  Since none of the answers given deal with actually changing code, which is what you show, it would be nice to know what you really want.

Comment: @jimmcnamara Not in bash script, it's in a PL/SQL Package, think it easy, just give you this string as input, please implement a function returns the string I want. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(line,
              '(.*\){3})')||
    REPLACE(SUBSTR(line,
            LENGTH(
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(line,
              '(.*\){3})'))),',NULL','')
FROM mystring;
```

You can see it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/288a4/13/0

This first extracts the part which ends with 3 `)`s. Then within the other part of the string replaces every occurrence of `,NULL`.

***NOTE:*** this might be not the most beautiful solution, and it might be done with better regexps (like look-ahead and/or look-behind). It might fail if your string contains other parts where 3 `)` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking for pl/sql-stuff, this might help you:

```
declare
  s varchar(100);
  dec varchar(100);
  rem varchar(100);
begin
  s:='DISTINCT DECODE(java_api_name,NULL,initlower(process(object_name))),NULL,field_description,NULL,NULL';
  dec:=regexp_replace (s, '(DISTINCT DECODE\(.*\)).*', '\1');
  rem:=regexp_replace (s, '.*(DECODE\(.*\))(.*)', '\2');
  rem:=regexp_replace (rem, ',NULL', '');
  dbms_output.put_line('whatYouWant='||dec||rem);
end;
```

Which gives you as result:

```
whatYouWant=DISTINCT DECODE(java_api_name,NULL,initlower(process(object_name))),field_description
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just updated my question, can you check that again ? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(str, ',NULL', NULL, INSTR(str, 'NULL', 1) + 5) AS new_string
FROM
(
        SELECT  'DISTINCT DECODE(java_api_name,NULL,initlower(process(object_name))),NULL,field_description,NULL,NULL' AS str
        FROM    DUAL
)
```

Result:

```
DISTINCT DECODE(java_api_name,NULL,initlower(process(object_name))),field_description
```

Comment: The first NULL is not necessary inside the braces, there might be a NULL before 'DECODE'

Comment: **Do not change the requirements.** I copied the string from your example. Next time decide what you want.